# Compiling kernel error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I am making  SYSTEM CALL for linux 2.6.39 kernel.

I have completed all the edits in the files. Now When i am trying to compile the kernel it is showing this error :

error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

If i remove stdio.h, Will the system call work ???

My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>

asmlinkage long sys_atvfcfs(int at[], int bt[], int n)
{

int i=0;
int j,t,wt[n],sum,q;

float avgwt;


 for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
  {
   if(at[i]>at[j])

    {
t=at[i];
at[i]=at[j];
at[j]=t;
q=bt[i];
bt[i]=bt[j];
bt[j]=q;
    }
   }


wt[0]=0;
sum=0;


for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{

wt[i+1]=wt[i]+bt[i];
sum=sum+(wt[i+1]-at[i]);

}

avgwt=sum/n;

return avgwt;


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be writing kernel enhancements when you don't know such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do'nt see any io functions used in your code, so you don't need to include `stdio.h`

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what your system call is supposed to do, but it doesn't call any functions declared in `stdio.h`.  (It doesn't call any functions at all, in fact.)  So it should be safe to remove that line.

`stdio.h` is a C library header.  It's available in ordinary C programs, but a kernel is different.  A kernel is self-contained; it can't depend on userspace libraries, because userspace libraries depend on the kernel to do their work.  Instead, the kernel has its own internal library of useful functions that you'll want to learn about if you're doing kernel development.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need stdio.h in kernel programming. If you need to print something, use `printk` instead of `printf`.