# Compiling device drivers to the kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to compile a device driver, but i get the following error,
and the same one for all following header

```
ddd@ddd:~/Desktop$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-19-generic/build  M=/home/ddd/Desktop  modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ddd/Desktop/message_slot.o
/home/ddd/Desktop/message_slot.c:23:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:309: recipe for target '/home/ddd/Desktop/message_slot.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ddd/Desktop/message_slot.o] Error 1
Makefile:1546: recipe for target '_module_/home/ddd/Desktop' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ddd/Desktop] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-19-generic'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
ddd@ddd:~/Desktop$
```

I compiler the program using the following makefile:

```
obj-m := message_slot.o 
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build 
PWD := $(shell pwd) 
all: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules 
clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The thing is, that by running the small .c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdli.h>

int main(){
  printf("test");
 }
```

with the command
gcc test.c -o test
everything compiles.
I suspect it's something with the kernel headers, but i've downloaded all headers as specified. I'm running lubuntu 17.10
am i missing something?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using stdlib.h within a device driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150611/using-stdlib-h-within-a-device-driver)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because i couldn't identify the problem correctly, but you totally fixed my problem. thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling kernel error: stdio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345778/compiling-kernel-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @DsCpp: Not sure what you mean by "i couldn't identify the problem correctly", but if you type error message you got (`stdio.h: No such file or directory`) into Stack Overflow [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search), then you got many similar problems about including user-space header into kernel code. E.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662480/error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error-during-make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdio.h` is user space header file not kernel space, that's why your `make` fails.
In driver program why we are including all `headers` because bcz its not having `main()` function, Right ?

when you will do `make`, observe your `makefile`

```
 obj-m := message_slot.o 
 KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

that means you are compiling as a modules and your source code will be in `/usr/src/linux-4`(some version).

for e.g

```
   #include <linux/stat.h>
```

not

```
#include <stat.h>
```

and

```
xyz@xyz-PC:/usr/src/linux-4.1.39/include/linux$ ls -l stdio.h  
        ls: cannot access stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

In your driver program why are you including stdio.h because you are not going to use printf, instead printk() ?

Yes in application program you can include `stdio.h` because you compiling using `gcc` compiler as a `file` not as a `module`.

I hope it helps.